# Failed to load response data when a specific function is called

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file called `api.php`, now inside of this I have a lot of `public` function. What I'm trying to achieve is call, from another file, a specific function of `API.php`. Essentially I perform the request, like this:

```
var postUrl = GlobalVariables.baseUrl + 'application/controllers/api.php/ajax_change_language';
var postData = { 'language': $(this).attr('data-language') };

$.post(postUrl, postData, function(response)
{
   //some stuff...
}, 'json');
```

how you can see from my `postUrl` I want to call `ajax_change_language`, I have inserted this after the file to call in the url. 
The request is performed successfully but the function isn't executed, I tried to put a simply echo or a var_dump of `$_POST` but the function isn't called. What I did wrong?

Comment: The return function isn't called?

Comment: `ajax_change_language` isn't called, in the network tab I get: Failed to get response data.

Comment: Oh, I though you meant the callback function of the $.post().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try :

```
$.post( postUrl, postData).done(function( response) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + response);
});
```

For information about `$.post` please visit :[$.POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: the alert is printed displayed correctly but no response result

Comment: I think there is an error or something missing parameters while processing the `postData`

Comment: @Sanchit Gupta That is why I asked him to get the actual error returned of the API call above. I am thinking that also. The request works, but the failure is due to the functionality of the function. I am currently doing Web API projects, and makes sense that this is occurring.  So I give your comment an up vote. :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with that api function, or not correct data type. Somthing of that sort. Try the following in your post method, and see if you get a better idea of the error returned.

```
success: function(msg){
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );


},
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("some error");
  }
```

Comment: Seems the json format at the end of $.POST, now seems working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Really? Oh, because if using JSON, you normally would do this for the data: JSON.stringify(data here). So maybe since you are just inserting an object, setting 'JSON' causes an error? I never use it like that, but something to look into. Well congrats mate!

Comment: @Casey, Thanks for Help :)

Comment: Wait, I removed the json at the end of post and the function is called but the content inside of it is never fired. Infact, even in the network tab I get: This request has no preview available.